# Flutter scheduled local Notificaton

Tags: android, swift, flutter, push-notification, localnotification

I have used `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule()` to schedule the local Notification and its working great.

When this **Scheduled Local notification** is send before i want to check App Is in **Foreground** or app Is in **Background**.

If Flutter app is Running means app is **Foreground** so I want that scheduled Notification as **In App Notification** and if is closed means App is in **Background** than send Scheduled notification as **actual Notification**.

**I Have Done this Functionality in IOS using Native swift code in Flutter But How can i do this for android side code??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be down without the help of native codes and will work for both ios and android (little modification to the code maybe needed).

First, we create a life cycle handler class that will extend WidgetsBindingObserver class. In short, this class is used in flutter to notify objects of changes in the environment. To learn more visit: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final lifecycleEventHandler = LifecycleEventHandler._();

class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  bool inBackground = true;

  LifecycleEventHandler._();

  initialise() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(lifecycleEventHandler);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        inBackground = false;
         print('App is in foreground');
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        inBackground = true;
        print('App is in background');
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, we will use this class from whenever we want our app to listen to changes. We can add this to our main.dart file inside void main(). If you want to listen to changes from the start of the app.

```
lifecycleEventHandler.initialise();
```

Calling the above function will add the observer to your app.

Now, inside your notification function do the following:

```
Future showNotification() async {
  if (!lifecycleEventHandler.inBackground){
    //Show in app notification
  }
  //otherwise notification in notification tray
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.... The notification is scheduled local Notification so the notification will fire at scheduled time right ? When the Scheduled notification fire i want to check that Boolean (inBackground) if true than send that notification else remove the notification and show alert box which contain Notification Title and Body. @md-kamrul-amin